# Find the Norm of the an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\{e_n\}$ be the basis for $l^2$ and $\{\alpha_n\} \in \ell^{\infty}$.

Define $Ae_n=\alpha_n e_n$ on $l^2$.

Show that $\|A\|=\sup|\alpha_n|$.

Attempt:

We have $\| A\| = \sup \{ \| Ax \|: \| x\|=1 \} \geq \sup\|Ae_n \| = \sup \|\alpha_n e_n \|_{\infty} = \sup_n | \alpha|$.

Also, let $x\in \ell^2$ with $\| x\| =1$.

Then we have $\|Ax \| = \| A (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n)\| \leq \|A(\|x_n \|_{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n) \| \leq  \|A (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n) \| = \| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n e_n\|_{\infty} \leq \sup_n |\alpha_n|$.

Could someone please let me know if my work is correct? If not, how should I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you don't take $||x_n||_{\infty}$ !**

It should be,

$$\Big|\Big|Ax\Big|\Big|_2=\Big|\Big|A\Big(\sum x_ne_n\Big)\Big|\Big|_2$$ $$=\Big|\Big|\sum x_nAe_n\Big|\Big|_2$$ $$=\Big|\Big|\sum \alpha_nx_ne_n\Big|\Big|_2$$ $$ \le sup_n |\alpha_n|\Big|\Big|\sum x_ne_n\Big|\Big|_2$$ $$=\sup_n|\alpha_n|\Big|\Big|x\Big|\Big|_2$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! Does the first inequity look right to you?

Answer (score 1):

No. Your inequalities are not correct.

$\|A(\sum x_ne_n)\|^{2}=\|\sum Ax_ne_n\|^{2}=\|\sum \alpha_nx_ne_n\|^{2}=\sum |\alpha_n|^{2} |x_n|^{2}\leq (\sup_n |\alpha_n|)^{2} \sum |x_n|^{2} $ so $\|A\| \leq \sup_n |\alpha_n|$.